# Change only one screen orientation flutter

Tags: flutter

I want change **only** one screen orientation in flutter,

In my first view I use **only portrait** mode but in second view both portrait and landscape, in my second view I write this

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
            DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
            DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
            DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
            DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
          ]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
            DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
            DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          ]);
  }
```

but when returned in my first view where I use only **portrait** mode and return in second view,  not recognize that orientation is **landscape** mode. All this time I not change orientation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's no need to call this: `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in `initState` and `dispose`. Calling it only in your main function before `runApp` is enough. And about your question, call this:

```dart
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
]);
```

before `super.dispose()`

Comment: It's work only first time, After returned in my first view and than second view, in second view not recognize device orientation